# NSAttributedString With UITextView crashing but working fine with UILabel?

Tags: swift, uitextview, ios9, nsattributedstring

I am using NSAttributedString and set on UITextview it's getting crash but when i set this text on UILabel with NSAttributedString so it is working fine. code is given below. Why it is crashing with UITextView?

```
       let label = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 400, 400))
       label.center = self.view.center
       label.numberOfLines = 0
       self.view.addSubview(label)
       label.attributedText = appDelegate.attributedText

       let textview= UITextView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 400, 400))
       textview.center = self.view.center
       self.view.addSubview(textview)
       textview.attributedText = appDelegate.attributedText
```

Comment: Do you have a crash logs ? If you set "normal" text (and not attributed), does it works on the `UITextView`

Comment: It's worked fine with normal text. when i use attributed text getting crash with this message -[NSBigMutableString characterAtIndex:]: Index 3364 out of bounds; string length 3359

Comment: You are not using "English" text I guess? I guess that there is a encoding issue somewhere, but could be a bug in iOS.

Comment: Yes i am using urdu text but i did not encode any text